# Are there copy constructors in Swift structures?

Tags: swift, struct, constructor, copy-constructor

It's known, that when assigning an instance of structure to another instance, or passing it to a function, Swift essentially copies the instances by value. However I could not find anywhere if we actually have control over this process, like in C++ copy constructors. My question is whether Swift has analogue to C++ copy constructors and if not, are there anything in the language what helps to take control over passing-by-value process in Swift?

Comment: It'd be helpful to know what your use case/end goal is. Not everyone answering swift questions will be familiar with C++.

Comment: What do you want to control? Value types are always copied implicitly. For mixed value and reference types there is the Copy-on-Write pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy constructors are implicit in Swift, and can't be user-customized.

They always copy all fields of a struct. For fields that are references to object, copying is defined as the increment of reference count (a retain).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is probably more or less apparent but i had to confirm. I would appreciate if you can provide any kind of official documentation / source which describes the rules of implicit copying.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind I don't know of any in particular. What exactly are you looking to verify/modify?

Comment: Originally i was looking for a way to implement deep copy of a referenced object, but at this point it's just pure curiosity if Apple clearly explained such a widely used feature of the language.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind I would specifically make a `deepCopy()` method. The fact that copy behaviour can't be changed in Swift has shaped devs' expectation of what happens on copy. An implicit deep copy would be "surprising" behaviour, even if it were possible.